# Discord.py bot.wait_for

Tags: python, discord.py

```
@commands.command()
async def verify(self, ctx, length=10):
        verify_characters = []
        for _ in range(length):
            verify_characters.append(random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits + "!§$%&/()=?`-.<>"))

        verify_msg = "".join(verify_characters)
        print(verify_msg)
        await ctx.author.send(f"Verify with the number {verify_msg}")
        answer = await bot.wait_for('message', check=lambda message: message.author == ctx.author)
        print("done")
        if verify_msg == answer:
            await ctx.author.send("Verified")
        else:
            await ctx.author.send(f"Verify again!")
```

Im trying to do a verify system, but after the bot.wait_for task nothing happens, i guess something in the line is wrong, has anybody solutions?

Comment: Where do you `wait_for` the message? Are you listening to DMs or where do you want to see the `verify_msg`? I always get `Verify again!`

Comment: I would want it to listen to the DMs, and when the User answered with verify_msg it should send Verified else Verify again

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Edited to show full answer.

Hey ho done it lol.
Basically the message object contains a lot of data, so you need to pull the content of the message using answer.conent.

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=message#discord.Message.content for reference

```
@bot.command()
async def verify(ctx):
        length=10
        verify_characters = []
        for _ in range(length):
            verify_characters.append(random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits + "!§$%&/()=?`-.<>"))

        verify_msg = "".join(verify_characters)
        print(verify_msg)
        await ctx.author.send(f"Verify with the number {verify_msg}")
        answer = await bot.wait_for('message')
        print(answer.content)
        print("done")
        if verify_msg == answer.content:
            await ctx.author.send("Verified")
        else:
            await ctx.author.send(f"Verify again!")
```

Give that a test run and let me know what happens ;)

Comment: Hey,
first thanks for your answer, but unfortunately still nothing shows up after i sent the message. Maybe you can show me the code you used for you Verification system?

Comment: I don't think I have it, I just remember doing it that way, let me build a quick discord bot and try and resolve your issue

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it

Comment: Just editied my answer, give that a shot to see if that worked.

Comment: So, i tried it now and this error comes up in the console: 
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: module 'discord.ext.commands' has no attribute 'wait_for'

Comment: change commands.wait_for to bot.wait_for, sorry I missed changing that one as I typically call my stuff differently. Ill edit that for future refernece

Comment: Did you try to run it? Because it's still not working for me or maybe you got other imports as me or intents

Comment: what is the variable name you have set for commands.Bot within the discord module, whatever you have set it to, that will be what you use, so for example ```commands = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>', description="Test for SO")``` would mean I use commands.wait_for(). It will vary but it using bot should work as that's what you have in your current question, and yes I did it works fine for me

Comment: Maybe, you can give mne your Discord/Telegram Tag and we talk there @Rexy

Comment: I will come back to give the answer on here once it is fixed, but feel free to contact me, Incog#2628

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be a `dm` command we can use the restriction `@commands.dm_only()`

However we then also have to check where the `answer` was given, we do that via some kind of custom `check`. I have modified your command a bit, but you can make the changes again personally.

**Take a look at the following code:**

```py
@commands.dm_only() # Make it a DM-only command
@commands.command()
async def verify(self, ctx, length=10):
    def check(m):
        return ctx.author == m.author and isinstance(m.channel, discord.DMChannel)

    verify_characters = []
    for _ in range(length):
        verify_characters.append(random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits + "!§$%&/()=?`-.<>"))

    verify_msg = "".join(verify_characters)
    print(verify_msg)
    await ctx.author.send(f"Verify with the number: {verify_msg}")
    try: # Try to get the answer
        answer = await bot.wait_for("message", check=check)
        print(answer.content)
        if verify_msg == answer.content:
            await ctx.author.send("Verified!")
        else:
            await ctx.author.send("Verify again!")
    except: # Used if you for example want to set a timelimit 
        pass
```